# ffmpeg use resized image on the fly

Tags: ffmpeg

At the moment I can successfully add an image to a video in a desired position.

I can also resize an image to a desired scale.

What I am actually missing is to resize the image and use the resized one on the fly.

with this command I can resize the image

```
ffmpeg -i input.jpg -vf scale=320:240 output.png
```

and with this command I can add an image to my video

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i output.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=25:25:enable='between(t,0,20)'" -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy output.mp4
```

is there a way to concat the two operation **without** creating `output.png`?

something like

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i "-i input.jpg -vf scale=320:240" -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=25:25:enable='between(t,0,20)'" -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy output.mp4
```

thanks!

Comment: FYI https://superuser.com/questions/322216/how-can-i-pipe-output-of-ffmpeg-to-ffplay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i input.jpg -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=320:240[im];[0][im]overlay=25:25:enable='between(t,0,20)'" -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy output.mp4
```